# Hide Gherkin header comment in Cucumber output

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

We require copyright block comments at the top of our Gherkin files.  When running cucumber against these files, the copyright headers get printed before the features.  Any way I can prevent these copyright comments from being printed for every feature we test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options for you...

1. Patch cucumber/gherkin to allow an option to hide comments
2. Write a preprocess step that will strip out comments.

With regards to the preprocess step, here is a [quick one liner](http://soft.zoneo.net/Linux/remove_comment_lines.php) that will take care of it on a linux box.

```
sed '/^\#/d' myFile > tt
```

Of course, you'll need to modify it to fit your needs.